# Suppress hyphenation marking in selnolig

Tags: selnolig

The `selnolig` package is inserting hyphenation marks at any possible point. How do I suppress this behaviour?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage[english]{selnolig}  

\begin{document}

Th­ese com­prise the ff, fi, fl, ffi, and ffl lig­a­tures as well as 
the ft and fft lig­a­tures. Other f-lig­a­tures, such as fb, fh, fj    
and fk, are sup­pressed glob­ally, while ex­cep­tions are made for 
names and words of non-English/Ger­man ori­gin, such as Kafka and fjord.

\end{document}
```

Edit: (Just to sum up the comment section)
I obtained the sample text from http://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig (directly on the site and not the PDF file containing the package's user guide). The text from CTANs descriptor page contains these 'invisible' hyphenation points.
They get printed out when you compile text that git copied from the CTAN descriptor page with `LuaLaTex` (They are not inserted by `LuaLaTex`). The `selnolig` package was unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Just for the record: The `selnolig` package does *not* insert any hyphenation marks. This may be verified in two ways: (i) don't load the package at all and rerun your MWE; and (ii) insert `\selnoligoff` immediately after `\begin{document}` and then recompile. In both cases, the hyphenation marks show up even though `selnolig` is *not* active.

Comment: I noticed that the two sentences in your posting do occur in the abstract of the user guide of the `selnolig` package. However, if one cuts and pastes the sentences directly from the pdf file into your example code and recompiles, no spurious hyphenation marks show up. Please state where and how you obtained the two sentences shown in your posting.

Comment: I just found the package today and copied some text from the documentation to try it out. (i) hyphenation marks don't show up (ii) they still show up; If I type text myself everything works as expected. But why dose it come to this artefact when text is copied from the documentation?

Comment: Would you mind providing more information about *where* you "found" the package? Is it version 0.302, dated 2015/10/26, that's on the CTAN and is included in both TeXlive and MiKTeX? For sure, the pdf file with the package's user guide that's on the CTAN should not contain *any* spurious hyphenation marks of the variety you've encountered. If you obtained the package from a non-CTAN source, I'd be really curious to know about it, since clearly the pdf file got badly corrupted. (Full disclosure: I'm the principal author and the maintainer of the `selnolig` package.)

Comment: I just checked again. I seam to have used the text that is printed directly on the [ctan](http://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) page and not the one from the PDF. I am using MacTex2016 and TexLive says `selnolig` is up to date.

Comment: @Mico it seems to be related to `fontspec`, indeed `selnolig` appears to be innocent regarding displaying the hyphens. With this MWE: `pdflatex` without `fontspec`: no hyphens. `xelatex` with or without `fontspec`: no hyphens. `lualatex` without `fontspec`: no hyphens. `lualatex` with `fontspec`: hyphens are displayed.

Comment: @Georg -- One more thing: Which pdf viewer to you use? As I noted earlier: `selnolig` simply doesn't insert hyphenation points. None at all. If copying and pasting from the pdf file that contains the user guide yields unwanted and invisible hyphenation points, it must be because there's something odd going on in the pdf viewer.

Comment: @Mico I am not using any PDF. It is the description directly from the ctan page that I have copied.

Comment: @Georg - Many thanks for providing this clarification. Indeed, I too can now reproduce the issue you've encountered, by copying and pasting the sentences from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig. As the unwanted-hyphenation-point issue can be reproduced with or without `selnolig` being loaded, one has to conclude that these invisible hyphenation points are already contained in the text provided at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig. That said, I don't have the faintest idea how they got there, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't me. I wouldn't even know how to insert them in the first place...

Comment: The final sentence in your addition, "It is LuaLaTeX -- and not the `selnolig` package per se -- that leads to the printing of the hyphenation marks" is somewhat misleading. It turns out to be the case that the hidden hyphenation marks are inserted by the CTAN site software. When a text string is cut and pasted from the CTAN into a tex file, and the tex file then gets compiled with LuaLaTeX, the hidden hyphenation marks show up.

Comment: @Mico Why is it misleading? Only `LuaLaTex` prints out this otherwise invisible marks.

Comment: @Georg - I believe your claim is *somewhat* misleading, because casual readers of the claim might get the impression that it's LuaLaTeX that is both inserting and then printing the hyphenation marks. (Incidentally, your posting still leads off with the claim that "The `selnolig` package is inserting hyphenation marks at any possible point".) As we've learned in the meantime, though, the hyphenation marks are there all along if one cuts and pastes text material from a CTAN descriptor page. In my view, the fact that LuaLaTeX makes these critters visible is of rather secondary importance.

Comment: @Mico Ok I get what you mean now. I personally think that the fact that LuaLaTex makes them visible should stay in the post (because without that behaviour there would have been no question to ask in the first place) but we could definitely change the wording to make the statement even clearer. Do you want to edit it? Otherwise I will think about how to rephrase it tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a copy-pasting artefact. In the question the words appear with invisible breakpoints (such as those inserted by `ctan`). When reprocessed these get converted to hyphens. This can be shown with a hex viewer on the source file:

```
65 67 69 6e 7b 64 6f 63 75 6d 65 6e 74 7d 0a 54  egin{document}.T
68 c2 ad 65 73 65 20 63 6f 6d c2 ad 70 72 69 73  h..ese com..pris
```

The `c2 ad` character is UTF-8 for SOFT HYPHEN.

The solution is to type the text yourself :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{selnolig}

\begin{document}
% copied from question
Th­ese com­prise the ff, fi, fl, ffi, and ffl lig­a­tures

% typed manually
These comprise the ff, fi, fl, ffi, and ffl ligatures
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Mico I found out in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37234342#37234342) that `ctan` is to blame - sorry for the confusion, edited.